# Python - Click somewhere when the img pop up

Tags: python, pyautogui

I would like to write a program about the image may popup any time, and the action is to close the image, not to click the image. I have some idea about the code, but not successful: (image NOT popup, but still wait for 1 sec and to click top right conner ..)

```html
import pyautogui, time
while ture:    pyautogui.click(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\image.png')))  
time.sleep(1)   #I want to check image every sec
break
pyautogui.click(1880,15)   # after checking the screen for every sec, the image popup, and click top right conner to close it, finish
```

Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Try clicking in the top right instead of the center. Use a smaller image of the "x"

Comment: Hi, do you mean pyautogui.click(pyautogui.click(1880,15).(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\image.png')))  
??
an what do you mean by smaller image of the "x", what "x" is?

Comment: I think you should save the image of the 'x' (not the entire popup) and then check if that is there to be able to click in the middle of that. So, no.

Comment: sorry, I am a brand new student to python, could you please show me how to rewrite it? my problem that I am having is image NOT popup, but still wait for 1 sec and to click top right conner ..

Comment: You still want to click it even if it did not popup? The below waits one second and checks if there is a popup, and then clicks the 'x' if there was, and otherwise restarts.

Comment: yes, of course. no image, no action; image popup, click to close

Comment: Then the below should work given the coordinates you have are on the 'x'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You are breaking too early and clicking the wrong stuff.

```
import pyautogui, time
while True:
    #I want to check image every sec
    time.sleep(.1) #put time interval for checking here
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\image.png'):
       pyautogui.click(1880,15)  
       break
```

Comment: Thank you WHACKAMADOODLE3000, it works well, just one more little question: is there any possible to not waiting even 1 sec and close it when the image popup immediately?

Comment: would it consume much resource if checking every 0.1 sec? is it a good way to do so? do you recommend this method?

Comment: I'm not sure how fast your computer is, how urgently it needs to be clicked, or how long you will be running this for, so I am not entirely sure what the time interval should be. You can decide for yourself depending on the above factors.

Comment: Thank you very much , you are so knowledgeable and helpful